# Как сгенерировать последовательность из N убывающих дат (начиная с текущей) с интервалом в месяц

Tags: oracle, sql

Как сгенерировать последовательность из N убывающих дат (начиная с текущей) с интервалом в месяц?

Ожидаемый результат:

```
2013-04-01
2013-03-01
2013-02-01
2013-01-01
2012-12-01
2012-11-01
```

PL/SQL не предлагать, нуженo на чистом SQL.

Comment: А какая будет минимальная дата?

Comment: В идеале задаётся число N, и отсчитывается N месяцев от текущей даты. Если провернуть такое в запросе невозможно, то есть возможность вычислить минимальную дату вне запроса и передать в него.

Comment: разве что select из функции

Comment: Извините, понимаю, что вопрос вы уже давно решили, но не смог пройти мимо. Так как не понял в ответе, зачем брать любую таблицу и почему надо самому догадываться  о каком-то магическом числе 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select add_months(to_date('20130401','yyyymmdd'),-rownum) 
from y_log 
where rownum < 5;
```

y_log - любая таблица, что такое 5 - сам догадаешься

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```sql
with params (param, value) as (
    select 'months', 6 from dual 
)
select to_char (add_months (trunc (sysdate, 'mm'), -level), 'yyyy-mm-dd') res
from params  
where param='months'
connect by level <= value;
```

Результат как и ожидалось:

```
RES       
----------
2020-02-01
2020-01-01
2019-12-01
2019-11-01
2019-10-01
2019-09-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_CHAR(add_months(to_date('20150101','yyyymmdd'),-rownum), 'MONTH',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = RUSSIAN') as mmm, 
  TO_CHAR(add_months(to_date('20150101','yyyymmdd'),-rownum), 'mm') as mm 
from (Select Level From Dual Connect By Level <= 12)
```

немного подшаманил)))

Answer (score 0):

немного костыльный вариант, но тоже рабочий

```
select * from (select distinct trunc(sysdate - level,'MM') DT
      from dual
    connect by level <=
               (select trunc(sysdate) - add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), -12)
                  from dual))  order by dt desc
```